# git push --mirror without pull refs

Tags: git, bash, github

I'm migrating one git repo to another. To do this I'm using the `--mirror` flag for both the `clone` and `push` operations.

This works, except for a failure at the end, causing my bash script to fail, which appears isolated to pull requests:

`! [remote rejected] refs/pull/1/head -> refs/pull/1/head (The current action can only be performed by the system.)
 ! [remote rejected] refs/pull/1/merge -> refs/pull/1/merge (The current action can only be performed by the system.)
 ! [remote rejected] refs/pull/2/head -> refs/pull/2/head (The current action can only be performed by the system.)
 ! [remote rejected] refs/pull/3/head -> refs/pull/3/head (The current action can only be performed by the system.)`

Is it necessary to migrate pull requests?

How can I omit the pull requests when I do `git push --mirror`?

I've seen references to modifying config files, but I'd prefer to handle it at the CLI if at all possible.

Answer (score 10):

Using `--mirror` directs Git to copy *all* references, as if by the refspec `+refs/*:refs/*`.  (With `git clone` it sets up a *fetch mirror* as well: a bare clone whose default refspec is this same `+refs/*:refs/*`, with prune enabled by default.)

As you have seen, some Git servers refuse even forced updates to some references.  In particular, GitHub reserves the `refs/pull/` namespace for its own purposes.

> Is it necessary to migrate pull requests?

As far as I know, it's not even *possible* to do this on GitHub (though of course the GitHub folks might be able to do it from their end).

> How can I omit the pull requests when I do `git push --mirror`?

I think the simplest method would be to delete them after the `git clone --mirror` step:

```
git for-each-ref --format 'delete %(refname)' refs/pull | git update-ref --stdin
```

but you could also explicitly push the references you care about, which probably are just those under `refs/heads/` and `refs/tags/`, and maybe `refs/replace/` and/or `refs/notes/`.

Comment: Thanks! I actually just ended up doing `git show-ref | cut -d' ' -f2 | grep 'pull' | xargs -r -L1 git update-ref -d` which did the trick.

Comment: Awesome! They should include `git for-each-ref --format 'delete %(refname)' refs/pull | git update-ref --stdin` in BFG documentation.

Answer (score 7):

To avoid pushing the pull requests, you can push the refs you want (by naming them) rather than letting `--mirror` find them all. [This writeup](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/05/how-to-properly-mirror-a-git-repository/) offers an option (once you've arranged your local clone):

```
$ git push --prune git@example.com:/new-location.git +refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

You would want to generate that list of refs programatically in your script by listing `.git/refs` (omitting `.git/refs/pull`), to ensure that you pick up *other* refs that might be in there like [replacement refs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace), or other custom refs.

> Is it necessary to migrate pull requests?

I don't think you will be able to. If you're migrating from one GitHub repo to another, [the behavior you're seeing is expected](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/):

> The remote refs/pull/ namespace is read-only.

The `refs/pull/` namespace is specific to GitHub, so if you're migrating from or to some other service (e.g. Bitbucket) migrating a PR would require support on their end. [Bitbucket doesn't have support for that sort of thing](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/5814/reify-pull-requests-by-making-them-a-ref), and others might implement it differently.

Comment: Thanks! I actually just ended up doing `git show-ref | cut -d' ' -f2 | grep 'pull' | xargs -r -L1 git update-ref -d` which did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The command below is working for me:

```
git show-ref | cut -d' ' -f2 | grep 'pull' | xargs -r -L1 git update-ref -d
```

So, complete steps for me are:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/exapmple/repository-to-mirror

cd repository-to-mirror

git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/exampleuser/mirrored

git show-ref | cut -d' ' -f2 | grep 'pull' | xargs -r -L1 git update-ref -d

git push --mirror
```